# Redirect to different pages based on role using passport-local-roles

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I need to implement functions to redirect to different pages based on role using `passport-local-role` node module.

for example:

> 'admin' => http://domainname/admin
>
> 'user' => http://domainname/profile

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create for each role, separate directory in client side. In server side, store user role in session. Then create a function like this

```
function getRoot(request, response) {
    if (request.user && request.user.roleName === 'visitor') {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/visitor/visitor.html'));
    }
    else if (request.user && request.user.roleName === 'user') {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/user/user.html'));
    }
    else if (request.user && request.user.roleName === 'admin') {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/admin/admin.html'));
    }
    else {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/visitor/visitor.html'));
    }
}
```

Using `passport` package:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    if ((!username && !password) || !username || !password) {
        return done(null, false, {
            message: invalidUsernameOrPassword
        });
    } else {
        visitor.login(username, password)
            .then(function (result) {
                return done(null, result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                return done(null, false, error);
            });
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```